# AVAudioPlayer volume jumps when fading with setVolume(_:fadeDuration:)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have an `AVAudioPlayer` instance called `player`. When I set the volume as follows, it works as expected: the volume begins at 1 and gradually fades to 0.

```
player.volume = 1
player.setVolume(0, fadeDuration: 3)
```

But there is a problem when I try to go the other way, as follows, starting at volume 0 and fading in to 1.

```
player.volume = 0
player.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 3)
```

When I run this, the volume immediately jumps to volume 1 without any fade. This seems like a bug to me, because the behavior works with one set of values but not the other set of values.

I did find a workaround [here](http://blog.ericd.net/2019/05/09/avaudioplayer-setvolume-with-fading-properly/), which wraps the volume fade in a `DispatchQueue` call.

```
player.volume = 0
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.audioPlayer?.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 3)
}
```

This works. But I don't understand why you need a `DispatchQueue` call to make it work one way, but not the other way. Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm wondering if this is an actual bug, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong or not understanding something correctly.